# Extracting the boundaries of a pcolor in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a pcolor map like the following

[image]

Is there a way for me to draw the edges at the boundary between green and gray boxes alone? I would like the individual boxes in the pcolor map to be empty. I tried using contour but it seems to smoothen the boundary.

Most probably there is a simple kwarg to do this but I have not been able to figure it out. I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer is "no".  In general identifying contiguous regions and specifying their boundaries is a non-trivial problem (but common enough, look in image processing packages like OpenCV).  Since matplotlib doesn't need this boundary information to construct the plot, I doubt that it calculates it.  For the figure you show though, it wouldn't be too difficult to find for yourself, or you could increase the resolution so that the contour path will better match what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks tom10 for your comment. I am trying to write a code that would check the value of the neighbor and draw a line accordingly. Lets see if it works.